# Maven Profiles, Resource Filtering with hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to instantiate hibernate configuration file using maven profiles. My config file resides under `src/main/resources` and in the pom file I marked that folder to be used in resource filtering. Interestingly I can load the same properties from properties file whereas hibernate throws exception while parsing config file. Here is the code samples I am using.

POM - Resource Filtering

```
<resources>
    <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

File structure

`src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`

`src/main/resources/hibernate.properties`

Maven dev profile

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
            <hibernate.connection.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example_schema?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</hibernate.connection.url>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Hibernate config file sample

`<property name="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.connection.url}</property>`

Properties file sample

`hibernate.config.file = ${hibernate.config.file}`

When I run my application I see that the properties file is filled with correct values; but hibernate config file throws following parse exceptions.

`Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. Nested exception: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2155)`

and from same stack trace

`The reference to entity "UseUnicode" must end with the ';' delimiter. Nested exception: The reference to entity "UseUnicode" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

But in the pom I already escape `&` with `&amp;`. When I remove query params from url it works as I expect, how can I escape ampersand from pom file?

Comment: Apparently this is a problem about escaping & character. After removing that part it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure its going to solve your problem.
But, you can look into the following URLs:-
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

OR this:-

http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering

its been explained beautifully.
I don't have access to comment that is the reason i am answering.

Comment: Actually I already checked these links and I was expecting this to work. Thanks anyway